# Im trying to use the classes that i made(Vehicle and customer), but i get "TypeError: object() takes no parameters". What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, class

Im trying to use the classes that i made(Vehicle and customer), but i get "TypeError: object() takes no parameters" every time i try to create ether of this objects. What am i doing wrong?

```
import sys
import csv

vehicle = 0
customers = []

class Vehicle:
    def _init_(self, number, capacity):
        self.number = number
        self.capacity = capacity


class customer:
    def _init_(self, custNo, xCord, yCord, demand, readyT, dueDate, serviceTime):
        self.custNo = custNo
        self.xCord = xCord
        self.yCord = yCord
        self.demand = demand
        self.readyT = readyT
        self.dueDate = dueDate
        self.serviceT = serviceTime


def read():
    global vehicle
    with open('C101 BUENO.csv') as cvs_file:
        cvs_reader = csv.reader(cvs_file, delimiter=';')
        line = 0
        for row in cvs_reader:
            print(line)
            if line == 0 or line == 2:
                line += 1
            elif line == 1:
                vehicle = Vehicle(row[0], row[1])
                line += 1
            else:
                c = customer(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6])
                customers.append(c)
                line += 1

read()
```

Comment: It's `__init__()`, not `_init_()`...

Comment: im using Python 3.6.8 btw